# Include Entity only return one row

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

i have invoice class and share unit class

```
public partial class InvoiceAll
    {
        ...
        public int? status_invoice { get; set; }

        public virtual List<HistoryShareUnit> HistoryShareUnit { get; set; }
    }

public partial class HistoryShareUnit
    {
        ...
        public int history_approval { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Invoice")]
        
        public virtual InvoiceAll InvoiceAll { get; set; }
    }
```

and im using include in repository :

```
 public async Task<IList<InvoiceAll>> FindLimit(int limit, string cari)
        {
            IQueryable<InvoiceAll> invoice = from s in _db.Invoices select s;

            //untuk pencarian
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cari))
            {
                invoice = invoice.Where(s => s.Nama_Pembeli.Contains(cari))
                    .Include(c => c.HistoryShareUnit)
                    .Where(c => c.HistoryShareUnit.Any(i => i.Invoice == c.Invoice));
            }

            //untuk limit
            if (limit > 0)
            {
                invoice = invoice.Take(limit);
            }
            return await invoice.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
```

but the result always ends up with 1 row in Share Unit class

```
[
  {
    "invoice": "JKTNPP20120003",
    "historyShareUnit": [
      {
        "invoice": "JKTNPP20120003",
        "invoiceAll": {
          "invoice": "JKTNPP20120003",
          "historyShareUnit": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

the connection between table is correct. because Share Unit class invoice is same as invoice class.

But why they only return 1 result while in db that invoice have 3 Share Unit?

Can somebody enlighten me. Im really new in Entity.

Answer (score 0):

invoice = invoice.Take(limit)

This row limits the amount of rows you are querying. If the limit parameter equals to 1, then the query will only return the first item matching the predicate.

Comment: It filter the invoice output, not share unit output. And when i try it, i usually go with 3 or 5. so never 1.